# Problem with designing a Convolutional Autoencoder

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, autoencoder, mnist

This is my first question, so please forgive if I've missed adding something.

I'm trying to create a Convolutional Autoencoder in Pytorch 1.7.0, yet am having difficulty in designing the model so that the output size is equal to the input size. I'm currently working on the MNIST dataset, with the input tensor size being 1*1*28*28 and currently, the output is `1*1*29*29`...

Can someone please help me identify the problem? *Please note that I'll incorporate the learnings afterwards.

```
class autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_node_count):
        super(autoencoder, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5, stride=2, padding=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,32, 5, stride=2)#, padding=2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(hidden_node_count, hidden_node_count)
        self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 32, 5, stride=2)#, padding=2)
        self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,  32, 5, stride=2)#, padding=2)
        self.t_conv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,  1, 5, stride=2)#, padding=2)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU(True)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()


    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.size(), "input")
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        print(x.size(), "conv1")

        x = self.conv2(x)
        print(x.size(), "conv2")

        x = self.pool(x)
        print(x.size(), "pool")

        x = self.t_conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        print(x.size(), "deconv1")

        x = self.t_conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        print(x.size(), "deconv2")
        x = self.t_conv3(x)

        x = self.tanh(x)
        print(x.size(), "deconv3")
        return x
```

With its STDOUT being ->

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 28, 28]) input
torch.Size([1, 32, 14, 14]) conv1
torch.Size([1, 32, 5, 5]) conv2
torch.Size([1, 32, 1, 1]) pool
torch.Size([1, 32, 5, 5]) deconv1
torch.Size([1, 32, 13, 13]) deconv2
torch.Size([1, 1, 29, 29]) deconv3
torch.Size([1, 1, 29, 29])
torch.Size([1, 1, 28, 28])
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html) for ConvTranspose2d, here is the formula to compute the output size :

```
Hout​=(Hin​−1)×stride[0]−2×padding[0]+dilation[0]×(kernel_size[0]−1)+output_padding[0]+1
```

In your case, `Hin=13`, `padding=0`, `dilation=1`, `kernel_size=5`, `output_padding=0`, which gives `Hout=29`. Your output tensor is as it should be !

If you want to have an output of 28, add some padding. With `padding=1`, you will get an output of size `(1,32,27,27)`, because the output size of a ConvTranpose2d  is ambiguous (read the doc). Therefore, you need to add some output padding as well :

```
conv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 1, 5, stride= 2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
conv(randn(1,32,13,13)).size()
>>> (1, 1, 28, 28)
```